# Are there infinite primes among powerful order terms of Dirichlet arithmetic progressions?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am interested in primes and some of their varying characteristics which make them 
“qualitatively” different such as whether each prime generated by a certain type of Dirichlet arithmetic progressions belongs or not to the class of primes that are obtained from powerful order terms of that progression. Particularly, I wonder whether one can go beyond Dirichlet Theorem and establish that there is an infinite supply of this sort of primes in these progressions.

The case I am particularly interested is the case when d=1 and a=2k with k positive integer, but I would like to formulate the following **Conjecture** for the general case

For any two coprime positive integers a and d, there are infinite primes of the form $an^2m^3+d$ with n and m integers >=0

If true this would strengthen Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions selecting only the terms of the progressions whose order is a powerful number (a number that if prime p divides it, $p^2$ also divides it).

I wonder about the likeliness of the conjecture (which intuitively seems high) and whether there is any proof I am still not aware of. I welcome estimates on the toughness of the proof, as well as any hints towards its development.

Comment: It is unlikely.  The number of powerful integers less than $x$ is asymptotic to $\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}x^{\frac{1}{2}},$ which is the same order of magnitude as the counting function for the squares.  Since the question of whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $qn^2+a$ is open and notoriously difficult, I doubt any progress has been made for powerful numbers.   The simplest progression, the question of whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$, is known as Landau's conjecture, and has been open for 100 years.

Comment: On the other hand, Friedlander and Iwaniec proved that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2+y^4$ and Heath-Brown proved that there infinitely many primes of the form $x^3+2y^3$, which are likewise sparse. So the question might be just on the border of doable. 

Comment: @Felipe: Those are two hard papers, and the density of the smaller of those two sets is $\approx N^{2/3}$ in the interval up to $N$.  Proving an infinitude of primes on a set of density $N^{1/2}$ would be a huge breakthrough.  Perhaps it depends on what you mean by "on the border of doable." In a sense every problem is on the border of doable as you can never rule out the possibility of a new idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry this isn't much of an answer, but you might be interested in this [paper](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~subbarao/documents/Subbarao8.pdf) of De Koninck, Kátai and Subbarao.  Your conjecture is almost strong enough to mean that for any squarefree $a$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ where the squarefree part of $p-d$ is exactly $a$ (the difference being that you do not require $(a,mn)=1$).

Section 4 in the cited paper establishes a sort of converse formulation: for any powerful $K$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ where the powerful part of $p-1$ is exactly $K$ (with the expected asymptotics).  Of course this is a far denser set in which to look for primes, so this is certainly a much easier problem.  Presumably no significant complications arise if we shift this by $d$ rather than $1$.

Comment: Erick  i am very grateful for your answer and effort of summarizing section 4 of the paper. Its converse formulation pointed me a solution to the hidden question behind my conjecture. I was looking for infinite primes of a certain quality in Dirichlet Arithmetic progressions. They did not have to come from powerful order terms. Square free order terms is just fine for shifted primes with a powerful part K.
From my reading of the paper the converse formulation is proved there up to page 529. Do you confirm my interpretation?
Thank you very much. I owe you an aknowledgement in a future paper.

Comment: @Fernando: That is truly nice to hear!  I do agree with your interpretation, and I hope you are able to make good use of this result.  I'll be interested to see your paper when it is ready.